# Formatting the cells in Excel when Export through OPENROWSET 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, oledb, export-to-excel

I have the below query which exports the data to excel. But when I open the excel, all the cells are automatically changed to general format even i kept the format to numeric.
  `INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=E:\Temp Report Generation\custom_file.xlsx','SELECT * FROM [sheet$B11:AA11]')`
Please provide the solution to keep the same format when exporting the data to excel without changing the format manually by opening the excel.

Comment: A [simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+export+to+excel+formatting&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS727US727&oq=sql+server+export+excel+format&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.7820j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) should be your starting point. The short answer is you can't with a simple insert statement. Importing from SQL Server using vba in Excel is likely to be a less resource-intensive approach.

Comment: And you labor under false assumptions. There is no inherent "format" to columns in a table. What you see in a resultset is an artifact of the tool you use to view that information. Dates, numbers, GUIDs, etc. are all stored as binary values. Strings have no format other than what was stored during insertion or modification.

Answer (score 0):

Try VBA and set the cells range you need as numbers, e.g.:

```
Range("A:C").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

This will format all cells in columns A through C as numbers with 2 decimals.